# Two new scraper sites?

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

Just came across these google links when searching for some keywords in a MSE-answer:

https://tttm.hostkda.com/tag/collatz/
https://eeem.000webhostapp.com/tag/collatz

*(I've opened the google-reporting page but I have no google account so I can't send it to google myself)*

[image]

Comment: The second one already reports as having been taken down, and the first one never seems to connect for me. Why would you send this to *Google*?  My first reaction to something like this would be to send it to the contact form selecting the reason "Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution."  https://math.stackexchange.com/contact . What would google even do? Maybe strike that host from its search results?  I guess that would be a pretty good thing, if it is possible...

Comment: Oop, i see in a previous question you asked on this topic that someone recommended the google form in a case where the site was using some illegitimate redirect scheme.  That's a separate problem :)

Comment: @rschwieb - the idea of contacting google stems from an answer to one older request of mine here. It sounded to me as if this were the preferred  way-to-go for the SE-community.  (edit: upps, our two comments crossed)

Comment: Indeed, I see how you got the idea: but for the issue of reporting "duplicates" of stackexchange sites, I think the contact form is the go-to.  But feel free to do both. I don't see any reason *not* to ask for google's help in tamping down such stuff.  It doesn't look like "spam, paid links or malware" covers this topic though.

Comment: @rschwieb: well, that's even the way which is more familiar to me. I'll do that (but of course checking the existence and the behave of the scraper-sites actually)

Comment: @rschwieb:  There is an edge case that Google cares about besides malware and sketchy redirects, namely where scraper sites get higher search rankings than the originals.  It would be helpful to be able to report the search terms Gottfried used to share with Google.  Sometimes it is the result of a "new content" bonus they apply in search rankings that leads to that.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: For me the first link immediately redirects to a "travel deals" website.  The underlying domain hosts "free websites", so it is perhaps not surprising that someone would put such a gift to work in earning money redirects to a commercial site.  In any case the site is on Google's second page of results for the search terms shown by OP's screenshot, while the original MathSE post appears on the first page.

Comment: I've reported the first site to Google.